# Downward force applied at center of see saw

Tags: homework-and-exercises, equilibrium, moment

If we are given the length of a see saw of negligible weight, and the weights and distances from the center of the two people on the ends of the see saw, how can we find the downward force being exerted at the center of the see saw?

In my question, the see saw is 8m long, and a boy of weight 500 N is 2 meters from the center of it on one side, and a girl of weight 400 N is 2 meters from the center on the other side, , with her mom exerting a force of 50 N on her side to keep the see saw balanced.

The question then asks to calculate the moments of the boy's and and girl's weights about the center of the see saw, and then to

> Find the total downward force exerted at the central support of the see saw.

Now find the moments is easy, for the boy it's just $ 500 * 2 = 1000 Nm$, and for the girl it's just $ 400 * 2 = 800 Nm$. Remember that the mother is exerting $50 N $ on the girl's side to keep the see saw balanced (or so I calculated it).

But I don't understand what force is exerted at the center of the see saw, especially given that its weight is negligible. I really don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total force at the centre of the see-saw must equal the total downward force (due to the masses) of the people on the see-saw.

i.e. 500N + 400N + 50N = 950N

I can see why this is slightly confusing, it is nothing to do with moments, just equal and opposite forces. Since the forces are balanced, you can now ignore the fact that it is a see-saw, and consider it to be a solid object. The downward force on the contact point would then be the total of all of the downward forces on the object.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense... could you by any chance help out here, in a related question? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/152890/finding-position-of-object-on-plank-for-stable-equilibrium-using-moments. It's almost the same concept... does this mean that C and D will give the same upward force regardless of where the man stands?